# x-editable child click when using 'selector' option

Tags: x-editable

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L4ak52dg/)

Hello!
I'm using x-editable [`selector: '.editable'`](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable) option in order to make elements editable automatically when they are clicked and everything works fine until there is no inner elements in `.editable` element (e.g. when I want to use [wysihtml5](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#wysihtml5) on them)

If you somehow click on parent (`.editable`) (to the right side of it) element it is ok, but if I click on child (it has no `editable` class on it), problems happen: x-editable adds `editable editable-click` classes to child and begins to edit as text field.

So the question is, can it be handled by proper tuning of x-editable or the only way is making workaround with click events or even making a patch for x-editable? What would you recommend?

Comment: It is unclear to me what your intended behavior is. Should the child elements be editable but only separately, or not editable at all?

Comment: @Chris child elements should be not editable separately, only parent element should be editable so child elements appear inside wysihtml5 editor, not in their own text field

Comment: Wouldn't that just be this? http://jsfiddle.net/54gcb6g4/

Comment: @Chris In your example, if I change the jQuery selector from 'body' to '.editable', it works fine.
Is there a reason you have to use the selector option, as opposed to attaching the widget directly to the elements? If it is due to needing support for adding widgets dynamically, let me know, I'll dig up a link where I got around that myself using a simple click handler that checks whether the x-editable widget is already attached; if not, it initializes and invokes it, and on future clicks just calls the initialized widget.

Comment: @kitty How about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/54gcb6g4/1/

Comment: @Demonslay335 it looked like the second div is causing the problem. I only removed that div, leaving the js code unchanged.

Comment: @Demonslay335 Yes, this is what I wanted as workaround, so if you will post it as answer, I will accept it. Also, how do you think, is it expected behavior of `selector` option (making `.selector` editable, not its child), in other words should my code work just as yours?

Comment: @Chris sorry, but you kinda got me wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to cater to dynamic elements, I recommend attaching a click handler to a parent element which then invokes the x-editable widget. My working example attaches a delegated click handler that checks for the widget being initialized, and if not, attaches the widget and invokes it to show. If it has already been initialized on the element, it will simply fall-through to the next click handler for the element, which will be handled by the x-editable widget.

This solution will handle any new and existing elements with the class "editable".

```
$('body').on('click', '.editable', function(event, ui){

    // Check for existing widget instance
    if(!$(this).data('editable')){

        // Setup the widget and show it
        $(this).editable({mode: 'inline'}).show();

    }

    // Fall-through for next event handler

});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/54gcb6g4/1/

As for the selector option, I've read through the plugin's source code and it actually works similar to my work-around (means I was on the right track!). See line 1601 for `initLive` of v1.5.1. It seems that he is using `e.target` for the target, whereas my code uses `this`. Changing that in my code replicates the problem. It seems to be invoking it on the element that originated the click, instead of that which consumed the event handler through the DOM bubble-up. Might be a bug worth submitting actually.